# Python save serialization that correctly handles str/unicode?

Tags: python, serialization

Apart from PyYAML, are there any safe Python data serialization libraries which correctly handle `unicode`/`str`?

For example:

```
>>> json.loads(json.dumps([u"x", "x"]))
[u'x', u'x'] # Both unicode
>>> msgpack.loads(msgpack.dumps([u"x", "x"]))
['x', 'x'] # Neither are unicode
>>> bson.loads(bson.dumps({"x": [u"x", "x"]}))
{u'x': [u'x', 'x']} # Dict keys become unicode
>>> pyamf.decode(pyamf.encode([u"x", "x"])).next()
[u'x', u'x'] # Both are unicode
```

Note that I want the serializers to be *safe* (so `pickle` and `marshel` are out), and PyYAML is an option, but I dislike the complexity of YAML, so I'd like to know if there are other options.

**Edit**: it appears that there is some confusion about the nature of my data. Some of them are Unicode (ex, names) and some of them are binary (ex, images)… So a serialization library which confuses `unicode` and `str` is just as useless to me as a library which confuses `"42"` and `42`.

Comment: Are you sure you need to preserve whether info was `unicode` or `bytes` in the data? Can't that be handled in the method that performs the `load`?

Comment: Yes, I'm quite sure… For two reasons. First, Python 2.6 explodes if `unicode` is used as a keyword argument to a function (ex, `foo(**{u"bar": 42})`), and second I'm dealing with some `unicode` data and some `bytes` data, and it would be *very* nice if my serialization library would keep track of that for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [bert](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bert/1.0.0)?

```
>>> import bert
>>> bert.decode(bert.encode([u"x", "x"]))
[u'x', 'x']
>>> bert.decode(bert.encode({"x":[u"x", "x"]}))
{'x': [u'x', 'x']}
```

(to install, you'll have to manually install erlastic first, because of [this outstanding pull request](https://github.com/samuel/python-bert/pull/2))

Comment: Interesting… That does look pretty good. Although, I would have to experiment with it to see if the size of the serialized objects was acceptable… Some seem ridiculous (ex, `len(bert.encode(u"")) == 40`).

Comment: Also, no updates for a couple years and no Python3 compatibility. Use msgpack instead.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe just use Python's `repr` to store the value and deserialize it using [ast](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html)`.literal_eval` method:

```
In [7]: ast.literal_eval (repr({"d": ["x", u"x"]}))
Out[7]: {'d': ['x', u'x']}
```

Comment: This… Is actually fairly reasonable. However, since `__repr__` isn't intended to be a serialization format, I'd be weary of using it: it isn't guaranteed to be stable, and it won't catch serialization errors (ex, trying to serialize a `socket`) at serialization time.

Answer (score 2):

Looking for the same thing I found that msgpack-python 0.4 now supports str/unicode with the use_bin_type/encoding arguments:

```
>>> msgpack.unpackb(msgpack.packb(["uu\x00u", u"adsa\xe4"], use_bin_type=True, encoding="utf-8"), encoding="utf-8")
['uu\x00u', u'adsa\xe4']
```

Comment: Also, an empty string codes to one byte in msgpack. Can't do better than that. I really like msgpack. It's even multi-language and extensible.